# If no forms are open upon closing a form, open a specific form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a database with multiple little forms spread out across the database (as most are I'd assume, lol).  There are multiple ways to get to multiple different forms, however I ran into a bit of a naviational issue that in certain circumstances, when a user closes a form, nothing else opens or is open.  So I'd ideally like Access to check if any forms are open at any given moment, and if not, then to open a specific form (the databases "main" form).  I googled this and couldn't find what I was looking for (possible I google the wrong thing?), so I honestly don't really know where to even start.

I would like to create a function that I execute on Form_Close in order to check if any forms are currently open, and if not, to open a specific form.  Again, I'm not even remotely sure of where to even start looking for this answer, so I don't really have anything to start off my journey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be this:

Add this procedure in a standard module and edit the main forms name in there:

```
Public Function OpenMainFormIfThisIsTheLastForm()
    If Forms.Count = 1 Then DoCmd.OpenForm "YourMainForm"
End Function
```

In each form you want to open the main form before itself closes place this in the `On Close`-event:

```
=OpenMainFormIfThisIsTheLastForm()
```

That should be all.

Comment: How would I add Reports in that, too?  I tried ```if Forms.Count = 1 And Reports.Count = 1``` but nothing happened.  Should it be ```Or```?  I assume ```Or``` would cause issues because if there's a form open but you're closing a report, then things would go weird.

Comment: Try `If (Forms.Count + Reports.Count) = 1 Then DoCmd.OpenForm "YourMainForm"`.

Comment: Once again you are amazingly fast and dead on.  Thanks a million!